# Set of filters to apply for answer extraction and selection?

Tags: java, filter, nlp, text-mining, nlp-question-answering

I've been working on Open Source Ephyra code and incorporated the YQL API as a new source of KM. The problem is that Ephyra gives very brief answers. Even for open end questions like 'What is Chemistry?', I get one or two words brief answers i.e 'change of matter' or 'organic'. But such questions need to have more explanatory and detailed answers.

Is there any way I can modify this to bring me more detailed answers? maybe by removing the some set of filter and adding other ones.

This is the current list of filters by default:

```
// - answer extraction filters
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new AnswerTypeFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new AnswerPatternFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new WebDocumentFetcherFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new PredicateExtractionFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new FactoidsFromPredicatesFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new TruncationFilter());
// - answer selection filters
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new StopwordFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new QuestionKeywordsFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new ScoreNormalizationFilter(NORMALIZER));
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new ScoreCombinationFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new FactoidSubsetFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new DuplicateFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new ScoreSorterFilter());
```

Additional filter i can use are:

```
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new NumberOfKeywordsFilter());        
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new ResultLengthFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new AdaptiveNumberOfKeywordsFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new DirectSpeechFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new NounPhraseFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new NuggetEvaluationFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new PreferNamedEntitiesFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new ProperNameFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new ResultLengthFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new ResultLengthSorterFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new SentenceSplitterFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new SubclauseSplitterFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new TermFilter());
AnswerSelection.addFilter(new TripletFilter());
```

But i don't know which of these are answer extraction filters and which one are answer selection. And i guess we have to follow some order.

Can you guys please suggest some order of all these filters? by which i could get the kind of answers i want(explanatory). I'm confused